# Javascript Float Becoming NaN After Use

Tags: javascript, virtual-machine, nan, v8

I have the following class

```
function Sprite( sprite, frameWidth, frameHeight )
{
    this.frameWidth = frameWidth;
    this.frameHeight = frameHeight;
    this.sprite = sprite;
    this.cycles = new Array( [ new AnimationPoint( 0, 0 ) ] );
    this.currentFrame = 0;
    this.currentCycle = this.cycles[ 0 ];
    this.scaleFactor = 1;
    this.pause = false;
    this.x = 0.0;
    this.y = 0.0;
    this.orientation = 0.0;
    this.transformQue = new Array();
    this.QueRotation = function( radians ) {
        this.transformQue.push( radians );
    }
    this.AddAnimationCycle = function( animationPoints ) {
        this.cycles.push( animationPoints );
    }
    this.Pause = function() {
        this.pause = true;
    }
    this.UnPause = function() {
        this.pause = false;
    }
    this.SelectAnimationCycle = function( cycle ) {
        this.currentFrame = 0;
        this.currentCycle = this.cycles[ cycle ];
    }
    this.Forward = function() {
        this.x += Math.cos( this.orientation ) * grid.UnitToPixelX( canvas );
        this.y += Math.sin( this.orientation ) * grid.UnitToPixelY( canvas );
    }
    this.Animate = function ()
    {
        renderContext.save();
        var rotation = this.transformQue.pop();
        var x = ( ( this.frameWidth * this.scaleFactor ) / 2 );
        var y = ( ( this.frameHeight * this.scaleFactor ) / 2 );
        renderContext.translate( this.x + x,
                this.y + y );
        renderContext.rotate( this.orientation += rotation );
        renderContext.translate( -( this.x + x ),
            -( this.y + y ) );
        renderContext.drawImage( this.sprite, 
                this.currentCycle[ this.currentFrame ].x * this.frameWidth, 
                this.currentCycle[ this.currentFrame ].y * this.frameHeight, 
                this.frameWidth, this.frameHeight, this.x, this.y, 
                this.frameWidth * this.scaleFactor, this.frameHeight * this.scaleFactor );
        renderContext.restore();
        if( this.pause == false )
        {
            ++this.currentFrame;
            if( this.currentFrame >= this.currentCycle.length )
                this.currentFrame = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

If I in my render function, do something like

```
mySprite.QueRotation( .1 )
```

It works forever.

However, if I have a function that calls `QueRotation` such as

```
function MySpriteClockWise() {
    mySprite.QueRotation( Math.PI / 2 );
}
```

It goes to NaN.

Stranger still, `this.orientation = 0.0;` however if I don't touch the `QueRotation` function inside my render function, it goes to NaN! Even after being assigned simply to zero and having not touched it! If I do a function such as:

```
starting = 0;

function MySpriteStart() {
    if( starting++ < 4 )
        MySpriteClockWise();
}
```

and watch the value in the console, it calculates just fine for as many times as I want to run the function, but as soon as it is done in the render function, it becomes NaN!

Its as if JS doesent think I need the value anymore, even if I make a function like:

```
this.Forward = function() {
    this.x += Math.cos( this.orientation ) * grid.UnitToPixelX( canvas );
    this.y += Math.sin( this.orientation ) * grid.UnitToPixelY( canvas );
}
```

to try to coax it into not throwing the value away, it still does! This is a big problem, because I am scripting through [lua](http://www.moonshinejs.org/) the whole point of the project is for (a coding tutorial) users to be able to script to control "mySprite" (a charachter) through lua to learn! This behavior is in both firefox and chromium. Please help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a bug that explained the issue, I was hasty, it seemed like something to conserve on resources too me, I am sorry.

Comment: It would be nice to post the solution here so that others may benefit who may run into a similar issue. -- Regarding conserving resources: you could improve efficiency by installing functions on the prototype. The pattern `this.QueRotation = function(...){...}` creates a new copy of the function object for every `Sprite` instance. The recommended path is to write `Sprite.prototype.QueRotation = function(...) {...}`, that way only one copy of `QueRotation` is created under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

When calling `mySprite.QueRotation( .1 )` the `this` inside `QueRotation` function doesn't
point to  `mySprite` object. Use arrow function instead

```
this.QueRotation = ( radians ) => {
   this.transformQue.push( radians );
}
```

**Edit**:

It seems you do not have ES6 support. In this case use this when calling `QueRotation` function

```
mySprite.QueRotation.call(mySprite, .1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>`

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain In which environment you are running your JavaScript

Comment: my bad, I made a mistake, however, when I did get it to work, it didnt change anything. I even set mySprite.orientation in the console, then it went right back to NaN

Comment: I mean that it compiled, I made a syntax error in the first comment, however, it did not solve the problem in the question.

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/WzDd8KHC/pic.png that is with `this.QueRotation = ( radians ) => {
   this.transformQue.push( radians );
}` running

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `this` inside `QueRotation` is perfectly fine. No arrow functions are needed in this case.